# Apache Rewriting hide extensions

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, apache2

Maybe just a tricky question,

But for my website, I use to hide files extensions in url using this line in my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.php [L]
```

It worked perfectly on my mutualized server, but not in local with MAMP. But it was not a big deal.

But now I've chosen a dedicated server, and I'm having the real problem, not working on it. It's strange because other rewriting rules like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ place.php?place=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ place.php?place=$1 [L]
```

are perfectly working!!

Is there a specific configuration to be made in some Apache file in order to have this thing working?

Thanx a lot for your time

Guillaume

EDIT : More of my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php?$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^fullscreen-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ place.php?place=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fullscreen-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ place.php?place=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fullscreen-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ fullscreen.php?place=$1&event=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^fullscreen-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ fullscreen.php?place=$1&event=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^fullscreen-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ fullscreen.php?place=$1&event=$2&sort=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^fullscreen-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ fullscreen.php?place=$1&event=$2&sort=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed That:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options +MultiViews
```

Answer (score 0):

check for the `mod_rewrite` if it is enable with php
by doing

```
echo phpinfo();
```

so you have to enable `mod_rewrite` in `httpd.conf` file

> 1. Find the httpd.conf file (usually you will find it in a folder
>      called conf, config or something along
>      those lines) if you have LAMP platform file can be found here /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
> 2. Inside the httpd.conf file uncomment the line LoadModule
>      rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
>      (remove the pound '#' sign from in
>      front of the line)
> 3. Also find the line ClearModuleList is uncommented then
>      find and make sure that the line
>      AddModule mod_rewrite.c is not
>      commented out.

http://www.tutorio.com/tutorial/enable-mod-rewrite-on-apache

Comment: I don't have any mod_rewrite line in my phpinfo. The only "rewrite" occurrence I have is url_rewriter.tags

Comment: Do you have LAMP platform on dedicated server?

Comment: It's a gentoo distrib with apache php mysql and all. Normally :)

Comment: Can you tell me apache version? if it is apache2, get the file here /etc/apache2/httpd.conf make updates for mod_rewrite and restart apache /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: It's usr/local/apache for me but I have not a mod_rewrite in /modules. Btw, how to explain that some rewriting are working and just not this one?

Comment: You can find here the two phpinfo : first one, which is perfectly working on a mutualised : http://votrequestion.com/phpinfo (see, it should be phpinfo.php in the url, it's working) and the second one on the dedicated server, not working : https://ks3093848.kimsufi.com/test.php

Answer (score 0):

enabled overriding ( `AllowOverride All` ) in your httpd.conf

Comment: as far as i know mod_rewrite is enabled by default so if your htaccess files don't work at all problem is AllowOverride, q:have you restarted apache after enabling override option?

Comment: Yep I've done it, every time smth is changed in my config. It also seems that mod_rewrite is enabled because I can rewrite something like /friendly_url to mypage.php?var=friendly_url. I've just the problem with index -> index.php :(

Comment: can you paste whole .htaccess somewhere & give an example of url that doesn't work with hiding extension?

Comment: Everything works perfectly except the first rule. 

Eg: fullscreen-place-event call the page fullscreen.php?place=place&event=event but index dont call index.php 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fullscreen-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ place.php?place=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fullscreen-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ fullscreen.php?place=$1&event=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^fullscreen-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ fullscreen.php?place=$1&event=$2 [L]

Comment: I'v put more of my .htaccess in my post by editing it it's more clear.

What's working: /fullscreen-place-event is perfectly working by calling my page fullscreen.php?place=place&event=event

What' not working: /page don't call page.php
And that works on my mutu, not on my dedicated one..

Comment: well! that's odd because you have "RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php?$1 [L]" as first rule which matches rules below it, so actually you shouldn't get fullscreen-place-event directed to fullscreen.php